# Visual Studio for mac cannot read anything. All text and code is blocks

Tags: macos, visual-studio

[image: Picture of IDE]

Not sure what caused this. How do you fix this?

Comment: What have you done to resolve the issue?

Comment: All I have tried was uninstalling VS and reinstalling but that did not work. Now I did a more complete uninstall and trying to reinstall it. I ran this uninstall script found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/uninstall

Comment: A clean install did not work. I am still having the same issue

Comment: Is that what you get when you run the application or try to open a solution? Have you tried running virus scan, disk check, and updates? Do you get same behavior with other applications.

Comment: I fixed it. Somehow my mono install got messed up during an update. So I uninstalled VS. Then I reinstalled mono then reinstall VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. Somehow my mono install got messed up during an update. So I uninstalled VS. Then I reinstalled mono then reinstall VS.